# World Time Script

Tags: scripting, time

I have an online website portfolio and I want to put their the current time in our country and also I want to put the weather update there. If my clients browse it they will see the time in our country.
**My question is:**

What script should I used?

**Example:** I live in Philippines so thats GMT+08:00
Then, when someone browse my website from any country they will see the Philippine current time not their computer's time.

Comment: Check out iGoogle widgets http://www.google.com/ig?hl=en

Comment: Could you add more detail please? You want to do this in Javascript, or on the server, or what? Also, what time are you trying to put on the screen? The viewer's current clock time, your server's current clock time or some other clock time (neither server or client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the time on client side that is through java script instead of server side. Then time will be displayed based on client side time zone.

--Sameer

Comment: Thank you. That's a very good idea. But the problem is, in some cities there will be a late or advance in the time. But I think that's okay.